# Unable to retrieve data from JSON in Firebase Database Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I took a risk to use Firebase for my final project. I am not able to retrieve my data from Firebase Database. I have no idea where I'm wrong. Please enlighten me.

Main file:

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

@IBOutlet var placename: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var placetype: UILabel!

var SiasuObj = [siasuObj]()
var PlaceObj = [placeObj]()

var planPriceLevel = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchData()

    findPlaceToEat()
}

func fetchData(){

    //var planPriceLevel = ""
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    //I can't pass through this part

ref.child("ios_entry").child(user!.uid).child("Budget").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
        (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let SiasuObj = siasuObj()
            SiasuObj.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
            self.SiasuObj.append(SiasuObj)
            print("Total budget")
            print(SiasuObj.total_budget, SiasuObj.total_day, SiasuObj.total_pax)
            SiasuObj.total_budget = dictionary ["total_budget"] as! String
            SiasuObj.total_day = dictionary["total_day"] as! String
            SiasuObj.total_pax = dictionary["total_pax"] as! String

            let  total_budget:Int32? = Int32(SiasuObj.total_budget);
            print(total_budget)
            let total_day:Int32? = Int32(SiasuObj.total_day);
            print(total_day)
            let total_pax:Int32? = Int32(SiasuObj.total_pax);
            print(total_pax)

            let budgetPerPax = (total_budget! / total_pax!) / (total_day! * 3);

            if(budgetPerPax < 50){
                self.planPriceLevel = "1";
                self.findPlaceToEat();
            }else if(budgetPerPax <= 150){
                self.planPriceLevel = "2";
                self.findPlaceToEat();
            }else if(budgetPerPax > 150){
                self.planPriceLevel = "3";
                self.findPlaceToEat();
            }
        }

        }, withCancelBlock: nil)
}

func findPlaceToEat(){
    print("inside findPlaceToEat()")

    print("Plan price level")
    print(planPriceLevel)
    //let pricelevel = String(planPriceLevel)
   // print("pricelevel")
    //print(pricelevel)

    ref.child("places_detail").child("price_level").child(planPriceLevel).childByAutoId().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock:{
        (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let PlaceObj = placeObj()
            //placeObj.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)

            //self.PlaceObj.append(PlaceObj)
            print("Whatever")
            print(PlaceObj.place_name, PlaceObj.place_type)
            PlaceObj.place_name = dictionary["place_name"] as! String
            PlaceObj.place_type = dictionary["place_type"] as! String
            PlaceObj.price_range = dictionary["price_range"] as! String
            PlaceObj.vegan_type = dictionary["vegan_type"] as! String
            PlaceObj.website = dictionary["website"] as! String



            self.placename.text = PlaceObj.place_name;


        }
    }, withCancelBlock: nil)
}
```

Class file:

```
class placeObj: NSObject {

var place_name : String!
var place_type : String!
var price_range : String!
var vegan_type : String!
var website : String!
}
```

Comment: can you please post your firebase structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
ref.child("places_detail").child("price_level").child(planPriceLevel).childByAutoId().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock:{
    (snapshot) in
```

to this:

```
ref.child("places_detail").child("price_level").child(planPriceLevel).childByAutoId().observeEventType(.Value, withBlock:{
    (snapshot) in
```

ObserveEvent type is **.ChildAdded** only gives you information when new child is added. That's why use **.Value**

One more important thing to check is reference URL. Check you have correct base URL in Google-Info.plist or not

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `.observeEventType(.ChildAdded)`, use `.value` as it child added will only fetch data when new entry has been added to firebase.

To read data at a path and listen for changes, use the `observeEventType:withBlock` or `observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock` methods of `FIRDatabaseReference` to observe `FIRDataEventTypeValue` events.

**FIRDataEventTypeValue**:  Read and listen for changes to the entire contents of a path.

> **Firebase documentation** says:   You can use the `FIRDataEventTypeValue` event to read the data at a given path, as it
>   exists at the time of the event. This method is triggered once when
>   the listener is attached and again every time the data, including any
>   children, changes. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing
>   all data at that location, including child data. If there is no data,
>   the value of the snapshot returned is nil.